# Sort list of dictionaries based on nested keys

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

```
[{'AvailableOffers': (d7b000a:Order {Amount:1000,Name:"000091",OfferedC:"JD",SeekingC:"Taobao",UserName:"xalima",ValidTill:"2019-11-30"}), 'Participants': 2, 'OrderID': ['000089', '000091', '000089']}
 {'AvailableOffers': (d7b000a:Order {Amount:1000,Name:"000091",OfferedC:"JD",SeekingC:"Taobao",UserName:"xalima",ValidTill:"2019-11-30"}), 'Participants': 2, 'OrderID': ['000089', '000091', '000089']}
 {'AvailableOffers': (b222004:Order {Amount:1000,Name:"000093",OfferedC:"JD",SeekingC:"China Airline",UserName:"yunis",ValidTill:"2017-11-11"}), 'Participants': 3, 'OrderID': ['000089', '000093', '000090', '000089']}
 {'AvailableOffers': (d7b000a:Order {Amount:1000,Name:"000091",OfferedC:"JD",SeekingC:"Taobao",UserName:"xalima",ValidTill:"2019-11-30"}), 'Participants': 5, 'OrderID': ['000089', '000091', '000096', '000095', '000090', '000089']}
 {'AvailableOffers': (d7b000a:Order {Amount:1000,Name:"000091",OfferedC:"JD",SeekingC:"Taobao",UserName:"xalima",ValidTill:"2019-11-30"}), 'Participants': 6, 'OrderID': ['000089', '000091', '000096', '000097', '000093', '000090', '000089']}]
```

That is the list dictionary I want to sort, what i can do now is to sort

```
ListData_by_Participants = sorted(ListData, key=itemgetter("Participants"))
```

What i want to get help is

```
ListData_by_Validity = sorted(ListData,
                              key=itemgetter("AvailableOffers")("ValidTill"))
```

is there a way to manage this ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to sort `ListData` based on `'AvailableOffers'` and for the element where `'AvailableOffers'` hold the same value, you want to sort on `'ValidTill'`?

Comment: Yeah Thats what i want

Comment: What is `(d7b000a:Order{..})` as the value of `'AvailableOffers'` key? It is not a valid data-structure in Python

Comment: thats a data returned from neo4j is node label its not a problem. the problem is sorting {AvailableOffers: {ValidTill: Value }}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to sort *list of dictionary with nested keys*, you may use *lambda expression* as:

```
my_dict_list = [{'parent_key': {'my_key_1': 10, 'my_key_2': 2}},
                {'parent_key': {'my_key_1': 5, 'my_key_2': 4}},
                {'parent_key': {'my_key_1': 10, 'my_key_2': 6}},
                {'parent_key': {'my_key_1': 5, 'my_key_2': 2}},
                {'parent_key': {'my_key_1': 10, 'my_key_2': 3}},
]

sorted(my_dict_list, key=lambda x: (
        x['parent_key']['my_key_1'], x['parent_key']['my_key_2']))
#  value of first 'key' to sort-^                     ^
#               in case of same value for first 'key'-^   
#               sort based on second key -------------^
```

which returns the sorted list as:

```
[{'parent_key': {'my_key_2': 2, 'my_key_1': 5}}, 
 {'parent_key': {'my_key_2': 4, 'my_key_1': 5}}, 
 {'parent_key': {'my_key_2': 2, 'my_key_1': 10}}, 
 {'parent_key': {'my_key_2': 3, 'my_key_1': 10}}, 
 {'parent_key': {'my_key_2': 6, 'my_key_1': 10}}]
```

Comment: my_dict_list = {{anotherkey:{'my_key_1': 10, 'my_key_2': 2},
                {'my_key_1': 5, 'my_key_2': 4},
                {'my_key_1': 10, 'my_key_2': 6},
                {'my_key_1': 5, 'my_key_2': 2},
                {'my_key_1': 10, 'my_key_2': 3},
]
Thats the style of my dictionary and i know i can sort by two key values ? what i want though is to sort a key wich is nested to another key like key=itemgetter((anotherkey)(my_key_1))